# Moving the camera inside a Frame in java

Tags: java, camera, frame

I would like to know how to move the camera inside the Frame in java. Ex:

```
frame.moveInsideFrame(pointX,pointY).
```

Comment: What camera? What have you tried? We need some more information before we can really understand your question.

Comment: Are you referring to a java.awt Frame?

Comment: ...what? I don't understand.

Comment: If I have a Window, lets say 500 X 500, and i want your view port to also be 500 X 500, how would I move that view port inside of the window to go to a different location in space? I haven't attempted it, as I have no idea how to move the screen inside of a frame. I thought it would be something like frame.getRelativeLocation(). Basically, I want to create a moving camera inside of a frame.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to move everything in the frame. For example:

```
private void moveInsideFrame(int moveX, int moveY) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfObjects.size(); i ++) {
        JComponent current = listOfObjects.get(i);
        current.x -= moveX;
        current.y -= moveY;
    }
}
```

(this is just example code, it won't really work. have an `ArrayList` of all of your components on screen and move each individually.)

Or, if you just put them all in your frame (instead of overriding `paintComponent` in a custom JPanel) then use `frame.getComponents()`.

Comment: An `ArrayList` is unnecessary; `frame.getComponents()` can be iterated over to save memory.

Comment: @Vulcan well, I was assuming he was overriding `paintComponent`. I guess I'll put that too.

Comment: That makes sense. But it is at all possible to make some sort of view-port that moves TO the objects instead of moving the objects inside the frame?

Comment: @DillonBurton just move all of the objects into the frame. You can't move the frame view itself.

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob Ok. I've just heard of it being done before and was wondering if it were at all possible.

Comment: How about adding only a wrapper Frame to the view Frame, and all the other elements to that?
You would only move a single Frame, instead of iterating through potentially dozens of widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider your outer frame as the "camera" frame, and you can create a "world" frame inside of it.
You can then move your world window using opposite coordinates as to emulate the movement of a camera.

To implement it, use an absolute positioning for the inner frame (i.e. no layouts).
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html for more details on absolute positioning.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a VERY bad idea. (also I already said this in my answer.)

Comment: Why is that bad? I'm talking about absolutely positioning only the viewport, not the elements inside it. Why do you say that you can't do that?

Comment: Never use absolute positioning, it is very bad practice. **NEVER.** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing

Comment: Since I don't have time to try and test absolute positioning in Java, I'll just give up on this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I think putting all your objects in a JPanel with a null layout and moving it as a camera is the best solution